Visual Foxpro 9 : Object ListBox
I need to display results in a cursor, which is received by the variable cListData. I need to display these results in a list object, so I have chosen RowSource = "aListData" and RowSourceType = 5 because I want to display more than 255 characters. After debugging the code, I see that the aListData variable is loaded correctly with the elements, but the list object doesn't show the text:
LPARAMETERS cListData

* Obtenir le message à partir de SQLMessage
LOCAL cPrefix
cPrefix = SQLMessage(81664)

* Afficher le contenu de cPrefix pour débogage
MESSAGEBOX("Prefix: " + cPrefix)

* Créer et remplir le tableau avec les données préfixées
LOCAL aListData[1]
LOCAL nLines

* Séparer les données en éléments individuels
nLines = ALINES(aListData, cListData, ",")
DIMENSION aListData[nLines + 1]

* Ajouter le préfixe seulement une fois au premier élément du tableau
aListData[1] = cPrefix

* Initialiser un tableau temporaire pour stocker les lignes séparées
LOCAL tempListData[1]
DIMENSION tempListData[nLines]

* Ajouter les éléments au tableau temporaire
FOR i = 1 TO nLines
    tempListData[i] = ALLTRIM(aListData[i])
NEXT

* Remettre les éléments dans aListData en commençant par le deuxième indice
FOR i = 1 TO nLines
    aListData[i + 1] = tempListData[i]
NEXT

* Afficher le contenu de aListData pour débogage
FOR i = 1 TO ALEN(aListData)
    MESSAGEBOX("aListData[" + TRANSFORM(i) + "]: " + aListData[i])
NEXT

* Définir RowSourceType et RowSource pour utiliser le tableau
ThisForm.List.RowSourceType = 5 && Tableau
ThisForm.List.RowSource = "aListData"  && Entre guillemets pour le nom du tableau

* Effacer le Tag du formulaire (optionnel)
ThisForm.Tag = ""



That is because the array you are using is a variable and it is going out of scope. Instead you could use an array propery. ie:
Public oForm
oForm = Createobject('MyForm')
oForm.Show()

Procedure SQLMessage(tnNumber)
    Return 'MyPrefix'
Endproc

Define Class MyForm As Form
    Dimension aList[1]

    Add Object myList As ListBox With Top= 10, Left=10

    Procedure PrepareListbox
        Lparameters cListData

        * Obtenir le message à partir de SQLMessage
        Local cPrefix
        cPrefix = SQLMessage(81664)

        * Afficher le contenu de cPrefix pour débogage
        Messagebox("Prefix: " + cPrefix)

        * Créer et remplir le tableau avec les données préfixées
        Local aListData[1]
        Local nLines

        * Séparer les données en éléments individuels
        nLines = Alines(aListData, cListData, ",")
        Dimension aListData[nLines + 1]

        * Ajouter le préfixe seulement une fois au premier élément du tableau
        aListData[1] = cPrefix

        * Initialiser un tableau temporaire pour stocker les lignes séparées
        Local tempListData[1]
        Dimension tempListData[nLines]

        * Ajouter les éléments au tableau temporaire
        For i = 1 To nLines
            tempListData[i] = Alltrim(aListData[i])
        Next

        * Remettre les éléments dans aListData en commençant par le deuxième indice
        For i = 1 To nLines
            aListData[i + 1] = tempListData[i]
        Next
        Acopy(aListData,Thisform.aList)

        * Afficher le contenu de aListData pour débogage
        For i = 1 To Alen(aListData)
            Messagebox("aListData[" + Transform(i) + "]: " + aListData[i])
        Next

        * Définir RowSourceType et RowSource pour utiliser le tableau
        Thisform.myList.RowSourceType = 5 && Tableau
        Thisform.myList.RowSource = "thisform.aList"  && Entre guillemets pour le nom du tableau
        Thisform.myList.NumberOfElements = Alen(aListData)

        * Effacer le Tag du formulaire (optionnel)
        Thisform.Tag = ""
    Endproc

    Procedure Init
        This.PrepareListbox("Item1,Item2,ItemX")
    Endproc

Enddefine

I didn't really understand your motive for using an array. IMHO, using an SQL is the best option for a list or combobox and its flexibility is amazing. ie: list Customer Companies but get any column's value (and no conversion is needed):
Public oForm
oForm = Createobject('MyForm')
oForm.Show()

Define Class MyForm As Form
    Add Object myList As ListBox With Top=10, Left=10, Width=150
    Add Object myInfo As EditBox With Top=10, Left=170, Width=150, Height=200

    Procedure myList.Init
        This.RowSourceType = 3 && SQL
        This.RowSource = "select Company as ShowCompany, * from _samples + 'data\Customer' into cursor crsCompanies nofilter"
        This.ListIndex = 0
    Endproc

    Procedure myList.InteractiveChange
        Thisform.myInfo.Value = Textmerge('Customer:<< crsCompanies.Cust_Id >> has contact << TRIM(crsCompanies.Contact) >> and max order amount is << crsCompanies.MaxOrdAmt >>')
    Endproc
Enddefine

